# XSL Fibonacci calculation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, fibonacci

I have a task to calculate a fibonacci series with XSL-templates and recursion, but I don't know how to summarize the series.

My code right now.

```
<xsl:template name="fibonacci">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>

    <xsl:choose>    
        <xsl:when test="$n = 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$n = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="$sum + 1"/>
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="fibonacci">
                    <xsl:with-param name="n">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$n - 1"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                    <xsl:with-param name="final">
                        <xsl:value-of select="..."/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know the background to the requirement. If it's an academic exercise, why are you constrained to use XSLT 1.0, which is ancient technology? If it's for production use, how high are the values you have to compute, and what are the performance constraints?

Answer (score 2):

The template should have the following parameters:

- `n1` - the first (previous) number in the series (default 0),
- `n2` - the second (next) number in the series (default 1),
- `num` - number of elements to generate, starting from 0.

It should:

- Print the current value of `n1`.
- Make a resursive call to itself with parameters:

  - `n1` = `n2`,
  - `n2` = `n1 + n2`,
  - `num` decreased by one (otherwise you would have an infinite loop).

So this template can look like below:

```
<xsl:template name="Fibon">
  <xsl:param name="n1" select="0"/>
  <xsl:param name="n2" select="1"/>
  <xsl:param name="num"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$n1"/>

  <xsl:if test="$num &gt; 0">
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="Fibon">
      <xsl:with-param name="n1" select="$n2" />
      <xsl:with-param name="n2" select="$n1 + $n2" />
      <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num - 1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And to call it you have to give only the `num` parameter,
as `n1` and `n2` have default values.

So the calling template can look like below:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <result>
    <xsl:call-template name="Fibon">
      <xsl:with-param name="num" select="8" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </result>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) `fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)` with seeds `fib(0) = 0` and `fib(1) = 1`?

A naive implementation in XSLT 1 would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template name="fib">
        <xsl:param name="n"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$n = 0">0</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$n = 1">1</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="n1">
                    <xsl:call-template name="fib">
                        <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="n2">
                    <xsl:call-template name="fib">
                        <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 2"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="$n1 + $n2"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="fib">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="10"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives the output

```
<root>
    <fib n="0">0</fib>
    <fib n="1">1</fib>
    <fib n="2">1</fib>
    <fib n="3">2</fib>
    <fib n="4">3</fib>
    <fib n="5">5</fib>
    <fib n="6">8</fib>
    <fib n="7">13</fib>
    <fib n="8">21</fib>
    <fib n="9">34</fib>
    <fib n="10">55</fib>
</root>
```

for the input

```
<root>
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
</root>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/3Nqn5Y4.

Comment: But as the number of template calls made is 2^n, this solution isn't really feasible in practice.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<xsl:template name="fibonacci">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:choose>    
        <xsl:when test="$n &lt;= 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$n = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$n = 2">
            <xsl:value-of select="2"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="num1">
                <xsl:call-template name="fibonacci">
                    <xsl:with-param name="n">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$n - 1"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="num2">
                <xsl:call-template name="fibonacci">
                    <xsl:with-param name="n">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$n - 2"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$num1 + $num2"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

You can test the code with this:

```
<fo:block>
    <xsl:variable name="fib1">
        <xsl:call-template name="fibonacci">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:text>fib1: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$fib1"/>

    <xsl:variable name="fib2">
        <xsl:call-template name="fibonacci">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="2"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:text>fib2: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$fib2"/>

    <xsl:variable name="fib3">
        <xsl:call-template name="fibonacci">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="3"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:text>fib3: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$fib3"/>

    <xsl:variable name="fib4">
        <xsl:call-template name="fibonacci">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="4"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:text>fib4: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$fib4"/>

    <xsl:variable name="fib5">
        <xsl:call-template name="fibonacci">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="5"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:text>fib5: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$fib5"/>
</fo:block>
```

Comment: But as the number of template calls made is 2^n, this solution isn't really feasible in practice.